# Handling a stringified JS object in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I'm able to return a stringified Javascript object to my C# project. The string looks like this:

> {"QuestionId":"","QuestionTitle":"hiu","OriginalURL":"","OriginalTitle":"","ChronicID":""}

How can I easily convert this to an Object with these parameters in C#?

**UPDATE: I got it working. See code below.**

```
SearchQuery search = (SearchQuery)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@filterParams, typeof(SearchQuery));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dynObj.QuestionId, dynObj.QuestionTitle);
```

using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(jsonstr);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", obj["QuestionId"], obj["QuestionTitle"]);
```

EDIT

```
string jsonstr = @"{""QuestionId"":""123"",""QuestionTitle"":""hiu"",""OriginalURL"":"""",""OriginalTitle"":"""",""ChronicID"":""""}";
```

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting and helps me understand what is going on

Comment: @user1274649 I tested them both before I posted. And `not working` isn't very explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So this is the actual string as it appears in VS:

Comment: "\"QuestionId\":\"123\",\"QuestionTitle\":\"title\",\"OriginalURL\":\"\",\"OriginalTitle\":\"\",\"ChronicID\":\"\"}"

Comment: this is what happens when i try to convert such a string "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'QuestionId'"


and this is what I tried implementing:

f (filterParams != null)
            {
                dynamic search = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(filterParams);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", search.QuestionId, search.QuestionTitle);
            }

Comment: Oh, and the search object is just taking each "Value" and placing it as its own seperate object. It's not taking the naming convention I desire. *grr*

Comment: @user1274649 Sorry but I can't understand you.

Comment: Just forget it for right now. Im going to struggle with it until it actually works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You want a JSON library for .NET. JSON stands for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, and it's basically what you pasted in your question.

I personally like **[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)**.

FYI, a "prettier" way to display the object from your question is:

```
{
   QuestionId: '',
   QuestionTitle: 'hiu',
   OriginalURL: '',
   OriginalTitle: '',
   ChronicID: ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. Turns out JSON libraries are already included in the project I'm working on. :)

Comment: EDIT: what do you mean display? That is the way the string appears in my code, so I need to parse it as is.

Comment: I just meant that it's easier to read if it's all tabbed out like that. JSON parsers don't care if it's all on one line or not, it's just for human readability.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a JSON parser

Comment: How is this helpful? At least link to one...?